# How to make a background of an element toggle a checkbox using only HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For example. I want to click on the red box and make the checkbox toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround the `div` containing the background color in a `label` pointing to the checkbox you wish to toggle. The label's `for` attribute will contain the `id` of the checkbox.

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="myCheckbox">
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
</label>
<input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
```